# Elementor (Wordpress): how to add category specific content for categories based on elementor template?

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I have a question related to Elementor page builder for wordpress.

We have category archive pages for a certain custom post type. These categories are using an Elementor **template** (which you can find in the side menu on **Templates -> Theme Builder** ).

So each category archive page is fully dynamic. It displays a list of posts belonging to the category in  dynamic way.

But what if I want to add a text for this particular category? Where/how can I do that?

In "Edit category" page, you can't add changes that will affect the design content, and there is no Elementor builder available there.

So I would need a way to define a text field in the template, but then it needs to show up on "Edit category" somehow.

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Hi Galivan, in this case - my solution for you is add a custom field for categories (i prefer ACF or PODS for this). Then just pull out this custom field oin your Elementor template.

Comment: Ok I see, thanks for the suggestion. We do have ACF pro. But where do I add text to this field? Does it show up on "Edit Category"?

Comment: Hi Galivan i've posted an answer about this below. Hope this help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to do that - all you need is create a custom field group as normal. But in the location setting, chose taxonomy equal to your custom post type as show in below picture.

[image]